# Linear response theory for a condensed matter system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, perturbation-theory, correlation-functions

i'm trying to understand the derivation pictures below for a perturbation in the form of an electric field on the lattice.

[image]

I understand that in time independent first-order perturbation theory, we have

$$\delta O = \sum_{j \neq i} \frac{< \psi_i| \Delta H| \psi_j > < \psi_j | \Delta H| \psi_i >}{E_i - E_j} \tag{4}$$

for an observable O
and in linear response theory the perturbations take the form

$
\Delta  H = O V
$
for an external source $V$ perturbing the operator $O$. I've tried a few times to derive equation (3) in the image using these concepts but am struggling to do this. Particularly because, in linear response we are usually looking at a time-dependent perturbation rather than a time-independent perturbation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit:
\begin{equation}|\psi^*_{nk} \rangle = |\psi_{nk} \rangle + \sum_{n'k' \neq nk} \frac{\langle\psi_{n'k'}|V|\psi_{nk} \rangle}{E_{n'k'}-E_{nk}} |\psi_{n'k'} \rangle . (4)
\end{equation}
Then, the change in a general observable O is
\begin{equation}
\delta\langle O\rangle = \sum_{n'k' \neq nk} [\frac{O_{nk;n'k'}V_{n'k';nk}-V_{nk;n'k'}O_{n'k';nk}}{E_{n'k'}-E_{nk}}]. (5)
\end{equation}
However I can't see how to simplify this further in order to get equation (3). I also am unsure at how to introduce the occupation number defined by (1) and (2).

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Please indicate where do you get stuck in the derivation.

Comment: Well i particularly don't understand where the form of delta O comes from. It looks similair to the normal first order perturbation theory term but with the added V, but i don't understand why the indices of V are reversed from those of O. Also i'm confused as to how linear response theory is being applied in this context as there is no time-dependence present.

Comment: note that the formula you wrote is the *second*-order perturbation theory. You see that you have there $\Delta H$ twice, indicating that the result will be quadratic in the perturbation. The result in the image-text is *linear* in the perturbation, and linear in the observable $O$. Moreover, the formula you used is for the (second-order) perturbation of the energies, while you are looking for the (linear-order) perturbation of the states

Comment: @yyy thanks for the response. I see your point that the perturbation to delta O is not linear. My question is how i would begin deriving equation (3) then? Is it incorrect to use the first order perturbation in the wavefunction due to the extra term in the Hamiltonian delta H (equation (5))?

Comment: the expression in eq. $(5)$ is correct, but plugging using it to get $\delta \langle \hat{O} \rangle$ will not lead to your eq. $(4)$. To *linear* order in the perturbation you get $\delta \langle \hat{O} \rangle = \langle \delta \psi | \hat{O} | \psi\rangle + \langle \psi | \hat{O} | \delta \psi \rangle$

Comment: @yyy I've reformilated this question herehttps://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688205/perturbation-theory-for-a-band-model after considering your notes. I still struggle to obtain the expression I reference (Equation (3)).